# How to update many-to-one relation?

Tags: prisma, prisma2

My schema looks like this

```
model Article {
  id          String  @id
  title        String
  isPublished Boolean @default(false)

  comments Comment[]
}

model Comment {
  id    String @id
  content  String
  articleId String

  article Article @relation(fields: [articleId], references: [id])
}
```

And I am using the `upsert` like this

```
prisma.article.upsert({
where: {id},
create: {// create code here},
update: {
comments: {createOrConnect: [{...}]}
}
})
```

But when removing the comment, this code does not work. As I can see, the code does not have any `disconnect`.

I want to delete the comment on disconnecting, but don't know how.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How to delete a record on disconnecting
2. Does Prisma auto-detect the removed comments, since they are not in the article comments array anymore? If it does not, what is the best practice to detect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the comments first:

```
prisma.comment.deleteMany({ where: { articleId: id } })
```

And it will remove automatically al the comments from the article because of the ON DELETE CASCADE

I am assuming that you are using mysql or postgres

Comment: This does not really answer my question. First, the comment must belong to an article, so it does not make sense to make it nullable. Second, I know about `disconnect`, but if the article is deleted, I don't need to store the comment anymore, and I ask this question to find a way to delete it after disconnecting. And the last, there is nothing in your code that could distinguish the removed comments and the new ones.

Comment: sorry I have misunderstood you, but you can delete the comments first prisma.comment.deleteMany({ where: { articleId: id } }), and automatically will be removed it from the article because of the ON DELETE CASCADE (I am assuming that you are using mysql or postgress)

Comment: Ok, please update your answer so I could mark it correct.

Comment: cool, I have updated the answer